# How do i get all my documents from firebase without it duplicating

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, vue.js, ionic-framework

How do I get all my documents from firebase without it duplicating?

```
<template>
    <ion-page>
        <ion-content :fullscreen="true" color="secondary">
            <ion-card></ion-card>
            <ion-card></ion-card>
            <ion-title>Explorer Page</ion-title>
            <ion-header collapse="condense">
                <ion-toolbar>
                    <ion-title size="large">Explorer Page</ion-title>
                </ion-toolbar>
            </ion-header>
            <ion-card color="success" v-for="image2 in image2" :key="image2">
                <ion-img :src="image2" />
                <div class="center" >
                    <ion-card-content  v-for="description in description" :key="description">{{ description }}</ion-card-content>
                 </div>
            </ion-card>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-page>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import { IonPage, IonToolbar, IonTitle, IonContent } from '@ionic/vue';
    import { heartOutline } from 'ionicons/icons';
    import ExploreContainer from '@/components/ExploreContainer.vue';
    import {auth, db, storage} from '../main'
    import { reactive, toRefs } from "vue";
    import { useRouter } from "vue-router";

    export default  {
        name: 'Tab3',
        components: {  IonToolbar, IonTitle, IonContent, IonPage  },
 
        setup() {
            const state = reactive({
                description: [] as string[],
                image2: [] as string[]
            });

            const fetchFeed = async () => {

            const sorry = await db
                .collection("post")
                .orderBy("image")
                .limit(1)      
                .get()

             if (!sorry.empty) {
                sorry.docs.forEach((doc) => {
                  const data = doc.data();
                  if (data.image) {
                    state.image2.push(data.image);
                      if (data.description) 
                        state.description.push(data.description)
                  }    
                })
            }
    }     
      

    fetchFeed();
    
    return {
      ...toRefs(state)
    }
    }
  }

</script>
```

When I run this multiple descriptions pop up on one post. I want it just to show the description that it came with.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you provide your state and what you expect to be in the state will be much easier for someone to reason about the problem and to help you...

Comment: i want it in a post state so the image and post comes together but i honestly dont know how i would do that